# ngModel data binding not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm following the Tour of Heroes tutorial and cannot figure out why ngModel is not updating hero.name or if it's just not updating the view. I type into the input but the displayed name in the view remains the same (Windstorm).

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**heroes.component.html**

```
<h2>{{ hero.name | uppercase }}</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{ hero.id }}</div>
<div>
  <label>name
    <input ([ngModel])="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </label>
</div>
```

**heroes.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**hero.ts**

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: did you tried ? ```[(ngModel)]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`([ngModel])` should be `[(ngModel)]`. It's called the bananas-in-a-box-notation ;) (https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3008-two-way-data-binding-is-just-a-box-of-bananas-in-angular-2-beta-1.htm)

Comment: I was afraid it was something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open AppModule (app.module.ts) and import the FormsModule symbol from the @angular/forms library.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
```

Then add FormsModule to the @NgModule metadata's imports array, which contains a list of external modules that the app needs.

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule
],
```

When the browser refreshes, the app should work again. You can edit the hero's name and see the changes reflected immediately in the  above the textbox.

---

**source:** [angular doc.](http://localhost:4200)