# Angular2 Select 2-Way Binding not updating

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, 2-way-object-databinding

so im trying to Bind the selected Item of a Dropdown to a Property with 2 way binding but the property in my typescript code always stays the same.

This is my Select Tag:

```
<select #select class="form-control" id="favouriteValue" ([ngModel])="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let value of valuesFromHomeComp" [ngValue]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

this is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-register',
templateUrl: './register.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

model: any = {};
@Input()valuesFromHomeComp: any[];
selectedValue: any;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
this.selectedValue = this.valuesFromHomeComp[0];
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngModel data binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101229/ngmodel-data-binding-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax, it should be `[(ngModel)]` instead.

As a hint: Its bananas in a box. The square brackets enclose the "banana" brackets.